# In Modelica, if I have 3 pulse signals feeding into a torque for a spherical rotation of a body, how can I quantify the force of each pulse?

Tags: object, simulation, modeling, modelica, openmodelica

Here is the diagram. The 3 pulses represent the different axial components contributing to the torque on the body.
[image]

How can I be able to specify from any of the 3 pulses the force it is contributing to the body?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Forces.WorldForce` and attached it to the respective frame:

[image: Box rotated by force]

**Note**: Connecting it to `bodyBox.frame_a` will not do anything as the forces will be absorbed by the spherical joint.

And the respective code:

```
model RotatingBlock
  "for \"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76061120/in-modelica-if-i-have-3-pulse-signals-feeding-into-a-torque-for-a-spherical-rot\""

  inner Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.World world annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-50,-10},{-30,10}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.Spherical spherical annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyBox bodyBox(
    r={-0.1,0,0},
    r_shape={0.1,0,0},
    width=0.2,
    height=0.2) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{30,-10},{50,10}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Forces.WorldForce  force  annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-8,-50},{12,-70}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Pulse f_y(
    amplitude=100,
    period=0.4,
    nperiod=1,
    startTime=0.1) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-52,-66},{-40,-54}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant f_x(k=0) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-52,-46},{-40,-34}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant f_z(k=0) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-52,-86},{-40,-74}})));

equation 
  connect(spherical.frame_a, world.frame_b)
    annotation (Line(
      points={{-10,0},{-30,0}},
      color={95,95,95},
      thickness=0.5));
  connect(bodyBox.frame_a, spherical.frame_b)
    annotation (Line(
      points={{30,0},{10,0}},
      color={95,95,95},
      thickness=0.5));
  connect(force.frame_b, bodyBox.frame_b)
    annotation (Line(
      points={{12,-60},{60,-60},{60,0},{50,0}},
      color={95,95,95},
      thickness=0.5));
  connect(f_z.y, force.force[3])
    annotation (Line(points={{-39.4,-80},{-20,-80},{-20,-62},{-12,-62},{-12,-60.6667},{-10,-60.6667}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(f_y.y, force.force[2]) annotation (Line(points={{-39.4,-60},{-10,-60}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(f_x.y, force.force[1])
    annotation (Line(points={{-39.4,-40},{-20,-40},{-20,-58},{-12,-58},{-12,-59.3333},{-10,-59.3333}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end RotatingBlock;
```